# Mongo shell updateOne gives error "could not be cloned"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is a sample of my document structure:

```
{
  "_id": "123",
  "Config": "XML stored as string"
}
```

I'm trying to replace a substring in the `Config` property for the whole collection using below code.

```
db.MyConfigs.find().forEach(function(doc){ 
    var newConfig = doc.Config.replace('Old substring', 'New substring');   
    db.MyConfigs.updateOne(
        {"_id", doc._id},
        {$set: { "Config": newConfig } }
    );    
});
```

I'm getting below error when I execute above code in Mongo Shell.

```
Error: clone(t={}){const r=t.loc||{};return e({loc:new Position("line"in r?r.line:this.loc.line,"column"in r?r.column:...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned.
    at Object.serialize (node:v8:332:7)
    at u (<Path>\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.34.1\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\@mongosh\node-runtime-worker-thread\dist\worker-runtime.js:1917:583764)
    at postMessage (<Path>\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.34.1\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\@mongosh\node-runtime-worker-thread\dist\worker-runtime.js:1917:584372)
    at i (<Path>\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.34.1\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\@mongosh\node-runtime-worker-thread\dist\worker-runtime.js:1917:5
```

MondoDB Version: `3.6.8`

Can anyone help with the issue here?

Thanks.

**Update:**

Updated with example for clarity:

Old Data:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "123",
      "Config": "Old substring config for 123"
    },
    {
      "_id": "456",
      "Config": "Old substring config for 456"
    }
]
```

Expected outcome after update:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "123",
      "Config": "New substring config for 123"
    },
    {
      "_id": "456",
      "Config": "New substring config for 456"
    }
]
```

**Update 2:** Tried using bulk update approach.

```
var bulkUpdateOps = [];

db.MyConfigs.find().forEach(function(doc){ 
    var newConfig = doc.Config.replace('Old substring', 'New substring');   
    bulkUpdateOps.push({ 
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { "$set": { "Config": newConfig } }
         }
    });    
});      

if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) { 
    db.MyConfigs.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps); 
}
```

Below is the response, there's no error but nothing gets updated.

```
{ acknowledged: true,
  insertedCount: 0,
  insertedIds: {},
  matchedCount: 0,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  deletedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  upsertedIds: {} }
```

**Update 3:** I posted the same query in MongoDB community. Based on the answers there, the conclusion is that the issue is due to my MongoDB version, the query works on later versions of MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

If it is the entire collection and you just want to replace a part, you can try to do something inside the query (or use a bulk update)

```
db.collection.update({},
  [
    {$set: {Config: 
      {$concat: ["new ", {$substr: ["$Config", 4, {$strLenCP: "$Config"}]}]}
    }}
  ],
  {multi: true}
)
```

Comment: I'm getting the message `DeprecationWarning: Collection.update() is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite.` with `update` method.

Comment: Also, this approach will not work since I want to replace a substring which is common in all the documents but the complete value/Config is different for each document.

Comment: Updated accordingly

Comment: I've updated my post with examples for clarity. Please check if your suggestion will work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried using bulk update, it gets executed but no document is updated, post updated with approach. Also, I'm not an expert in MongoDB so I'm doing the necessary reading as I go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not MongoDb professional, but faced with the same error while try to import data with `mongoimport`.

It turned out that `mongoimport` does't available in mongo shell, and solution is to run needed command in your default terminal. [See docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/)